# Не заполняется массив с помощью упрощённого цикла Java

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, случайные-числа

Пытаюсь заполнить массив случайными числами с помощью метода Math.random() в упрощённом цикле for (int i: array);
Однако он не заполняется, а все элементы массива остаются равными нулю (т.к. был проинициализирован вначале);
Однако в случае, если заполнять массив полным циклом типа for (int i =0; i <array.length; i++), то массив заполняется. Почему так?
Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double [5];
        for (double i : array) {
            i = Math.random();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Comment: потому что тут не происходит передача по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить просто и без углубления куда-либо, то  такая конструкция

```
for (double i : array) {
```

работает только на чтение. Под капотом это работа с итератором. Массив, условно говоря, в себе реализует методы `hasNext()` и `getNext()`. Первый из них проверяет на наличие у объекта следующего элемента, а второй - отдаёт его значение. Вот `for (X : Y)` работает именно по такому принципу. По сути в `i` будет лежать то, что было взято с помощью `getNext()`. Получается что-то типа такого

```
double i;

if (array.hasNext())
    i = array.getNext();

if (array.hasNext())
        i = array.getNext();

if (array.hasNext())
        i = array.getNext();
```

В итоге исходный массив остаётся нетронутым. **[Иммутабельным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)**

---

И ещё проблема в том, что double - примитивный тип, который не изменяется по ссылке. Если бы это был объект, то написав, например `i.userName = 555`, поле у этого объекта изменилось бы.

---

Возможно **[эта более подробная статья](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1983-for-i-for-each-loop---skaz-o-tom-kak-ja-iterirovalsja-iterirovalsja-da-ne-vihiterirovalsja)** поможет лучше понять этот момент

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() в цикле for each использовать нельзя, так как этот цикл не предоставляет возможность изменять данные. Его используют для вывода данных из массива. Для манипуляций используют цикл for.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).