# Как используя forEach изменить имена в массиве, чтоб начинались с большой буквы?

Tags: javascript

```
const names = ['vLadiMir', 'maRk', 'LoGAn', 'VicTOr', 'mAks', 'KaTe', 'alEx'];

names.forEach((item) => {
  item = item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase();
});

console.log(names);
```

Нужно используя именно метод forEach изменить имена в массиве, чтоб начинались с большой буквы, а остальные были в нижнем регистре, но не пойму почему это не срабатывает?

Comment: Тут надо внимательно почитать, что такое объект и что такое литерал. И так как в масиве у вас литералы, а не объекты, то item это не ссылка на элемент массива, а копия элемента. Вы работете с копией и потом ее удаляете. А если был бы там обект, то item был бы непосредственно ссылкой на него, и изменялся бы как вы и задумали. Но ваша ошибка в незнании разницы между объектом и литералом. Лучше почитать спецификацию и понять этот момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что метод forEach работает внутри как итератор. Изначально он  своё локальное хранилище (в свойство класса) заносит массив, а потом производит итерирование по массиву из этого внутреннего свойства, по сути, копии массива. Поэтому основной не меняется.

Есть примерно аналогичный вопрос-ответ
**[Не заполняется массив с помощью упрощённого цикла Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1378567/191482)**

только там *Java*, но суть та же

---

Если нужно через forEach:

```js
const names = ['vLadiMir', 'maRk', 'LoGAn', 'VicTOr', 'mAks', 'KaTe', 'alEx'];

names.forEach((item, i) => {
  names[i] = item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase();
});

console.log(names);
```

Comment: Странно, я как то помню менял через forEach данные массива. Видно там были объекты. Получается никак в моем случае через forEach это не сделать? И это вопрос не в том что строки неизменяемы

Comment: Просто map можно сделать, но тогда будет копия, а мне нужно через forEach изменить данные в массиве, чтоб не создавать копию, и не использовать циклы for

Comment: Объекты в массиве можно поменять (свойства в объектах)

Comment: через foreach добавил ответ..................... "Просто map можно сделать, но тогда будет копия" --- как я уже писал - foreach тоже себе в свойство заносит изначальный массив. так что он тоже делает копию по сути